# docker volume on file system

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file like that :

```
version: "2"
services:
  orthanc:
    build: orthanc
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports: ["${PORT}:8042"]
    volumes: ["orthanc-storage:/var/lib/orthanc/db:Z"]
    [...]
volumes:
  orthanc-storage:
```

1/ I can't understand how to define `orthanc-storage` with something like `C:/tmp/db`

2/ what means the `Z` ?

Thank you for your answers

Comment: yeh for the subquestion (I just found out in the doc). But I still not understand where I clearly define orthanc-storage path ...

Comment: You're telling compose that you want a volume to be created under the last `volumes:` statement.  Every instance of your app will cause a volume to be created in the docker engine and when the instance runs, it will attach that created volume to the guest instance at the path you specified **within the guest instance** at `/var/lib/orthanc/db`.  Run `docker ps` to see all the running containers and then create a shell to look in the container: `docker exec -it NAME_OF_CONTAINER sh` and then `ls /var/lib/orthanc/db`.  That's where the volume is mounted in the guest container.